# Explaining high voltage inverter principle (KIKUSUI COS5020 oscilloscope)

Tags: inverter, how-does-it-work

I'm trying to fix KIKUSUI COS5020 oscilloscope HV part. Here is the schematic part:

[image]

Failed parts were: transistor Q651, capacitor C655. At high temperature were resistor R657 and inductor L650 (both not damaged completely). I have replaced them, also U651. T651 seems to be ok - tested. But the schematic still doesn't work. Can someone explain the working principle of this inverter?

DC at J-32 is about 18V as should be.

Q651 transistor voltages:
B 1,28V
C 17,6V
E 0,73V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This is a positive feedback oscillator with inverted polarity current
  injected in to the base. The transformer inductance and Cap C654
  determine the resonant frequency.
- The 18V supply current is limited if Q651 fails with a short circuit
  by R657 and is filtered by L650 and C635.
- The failure suggests an excessive load current condition caused C635
  to fail open with excess ripple current heat loss and thermal rise
  and Q651 to fail in short cct mode.

  - Ensure a low ESR cap is used to replace C654.
- check U651 output is not low (<1V) causing CR651 to conduct and suppress the feedback.
- This Op Amp uses the scaled output HV by R divider in a DC loop to regulate the HVDC out.  (TP = estimate -2kV to -3kV)
- even though it appears to be a +ve feedback loop, the +ve diode clamp voltage doubler produces a -ve DC out thus making the loop negative feedback.

Comment: U651 output is 10V. I have tried C654 to replace with regular electrolyte, and now found tantalum capacitor. Still no luck..

Comment: Q651 must have sufficient hFE to oscillate. Confirm primary voltages on all Q651 pins

Comment: I have disconnected high voltage capacitor C667, and the inverter is up :) So I think somewhere is a shortcut after C667.

Comment: looks like a Murata part. http://uk.farnell.com/murata/debe33f472za3b/cap-mlcc-e-4700pf-3-15kv-radial/dp/2456077. replace all 4700 pF caps there and check diodes.  A HIPOT test is the sure way to find an arc defect necked after diode with -Vdc

Comment: injected ....... not necked

Comment: Now it's Y axis problems, 4 transistors at final stage had to be replaced, and still not working somewhere in the middle stage. Hope it will be running again soon. Looks like this oscilloscope received some lightning :) Thanks for help indeed.